# Maximum tile and texture size for tiled maps

Tags: opengl, libgdx, tiled

I'm currently making a game using libGDX and [Tiled](http://www.mapeditor.org/).

Everything was running fine until I changed the tile size from 96x96 to 300x300. Most layers are still displayed correctly but the tiles of a single layer are just black. I guess that there may be a problem with the large tiles (as there are some tiles together in one tileset bitmap the texure is 2100x2100 large). Are there any upper limits for tiles and/or tilesets regarding the bitmap and texture size?

`GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE` returns 3379 on this machine.

Comment: Doesn't really suggest a limit here: https://github.com/mattdesl/lwjgl-basics/wiki/LibGDX-Textures#hardware-limitations other than PC hardware of course.

Comment: Unless tiles are sized differently, I'd recommend a texture_array instead of an atlas.